# How do I download a .crt file to a certain folder/directory in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, command-line, ssl

I want to download:

gd_intermediate.crt

from:

https://certs.godaddy.com/repository

and add to my:

```
/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/
```

Then I would like to check if certificate works.
What is the most efficient command line command to do so?

Answer (score 2):

- Download the file from your link and (by default) the file is downloaded to Downloads in your users home.
- Go to command line (open Terminal from Dash) and type

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  ```
- And copy or move the file over to the directory using your admin acount.
  To copy:

  ```
  sudo cp gd_intermediate.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/
  ```

  or to move:

  ```
  sudo mv gd_intermediate.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/
  ```

  This will overwrite the current file if there is already one named like this.

---

Firefox has in preferences an advanced options that lets you view certificates. But I would assume the easiest method to test this certificate is to visit the website it is linked to and see if it still throws an "untrusted website" notification.